# Entity Framework 5 - Immediately refresh DbContext after saving changes

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I have an MVC application that uses Entity Framework 5. In few places I have a code that creates or updates the entities and then have to perform some kind of operations on the updated data. Some of those operations require accessing navigation properties and I can't get them to refresh.

Here's the example (simplified code that I have)

**Models**

```
class User : Model
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Car : Model
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid DriverId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Driver { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string DriverName
    {
        get { return this.Driver.Name; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public CarController
{
    public Create()
    {
       return this.View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public Create(Car car)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            this.Context.Cars.Create(booking);
            this.Context.SaveChanges();

            // here I need to access some of the resolved nav properties
            var test = booking.DriverName;
        }

        // error handling (I'm removing it in the example as it's not important)
    }
}
```

The example above is for the Create method but I also have the same problem with Update method which is very similar it just takes the object from the context in `GET` action and stores it using `Update` method in `POST` action.

```
public virtual void Create(TObject obj)
{
    return this.DbSet.Add(obj);
}

public virtual void Update(TObject obj)
{
    var currentEntry = this.DbSet.Find(obj.Id);
    this.Context.Entry(currentEntry).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
    currentEntry.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Now I've tried several different approaches that I googled or found on stack but nothing seems to be working for me.

In my latest attempt I've tried forcing a reload after calling `SaveChanges` method and requerying the data from the database. Here's what I've done.

I've ovewrite the `SaveChanges` method to refresh object context immediately after save

```
public int SaveChanges()
{
    var rowsNumber = this.Context.SaveChanges();
    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context).ObjectContext;
    objectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, this.Context.Bookings);

    return rowsNumber;
}
```

I've tried getting the updated object data by adding this line of code immediately after `SaveChanges` call in my `HTTP` `Create` and `Update` actions:

```
car = this.Context.Cars.Find(car.Id);
```

Unfortunately the navigation property is still `null`. How can I properly refresh the DbContext immediately after modifying the data?

**EDIT**

I forgot to originally mention that I know a workaround but it's ugly and I don't like it. Whenever I use navigation property I can check if it's `null` and if it is I can manually create new DbContext and update the data. But I'd really like to avoid hacks like this.

```
class Car : Model
{    
    [NotMapped]
    public string DriverName
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Driver == null)
            {
                using (var context = new DbContext())
                {
                    this.Driver = this.context.Users.Find(this.DriverId);
                }
            }

            return this.Driver.Name;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is probably due to the fact that the item you are adding to the context is not a `proxy` with all of the necessary components for lazy loading. Even after calling `SaveChanges()` the item will not be *converted* into a proxied instance.

I suggest you try using the DbSet.Create() method and copy across all the values from the entity that you receive over the wire:

```
public virtual TObject Create(TObject obj)
{
    var newEntry = this.DbSet.Create();
    this.Context.Entry(newEntry).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
    return newEntry;
}
```

---

UPDATE

If `SetValues()` is giving an issue then I suggest you try [automapper](http://automapper.org/) to transfer the data from the passed in entity to the created proxy before `Add`ing the new proxy instance to the `DbSet`. Something like this:

```
private bool mapCreated = false;
public virtual TObject Create(TObject obj)
{
    var newEntry = this.DbSet.Create();

    if (!mapCreated)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap(obj.GetType(), newEntry.GetType());
        mapCreated = true;
    }
    newEntry = Mapper.Map(obj, newEntry);

    this.DbSet.Add(newEntry;
    return newEntry;
}
```

Comment: What about my `Update` method? Should I also fetch the original object other than `this.Context.Cars.Find(id)`?

Comment: The `Find` will return a proxy object from the database, but if you are finding and updating an object that has been added locally during this transaction it will find the object you've added.

Comment: I tried following your solution but that lead me to `System.InvalidOperationException: Member 'CurrentValues' cannot be called for the entity of type 'Car' because the entity does not exist in the context. To add an entity to the context call the Add or Attach method of DbSet<Booking>.` I've added `this.Context.Set<TObject>().Attach(newEntry);` just after your first line and now I'm getting `System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.`

Comment: Just for a test can you copy all the values manually before `Attach`?

Comment: I just did that and now I'm getting this exception on `SaveChanges`. `System.Data.Entity.Core.OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.`

Comment: I think the problem now is that you're not `Add`ing the new entity.

Comment: To avoid the error message "The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified."  try setting the Id explicitly before calling SetValues. There is an example of working code here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16811976/150342

Comment: @Colin I considered that option but it complicated the answer because it's not generic without a common base class/interface that exposes the id property.

Comment: @qujck it's true that this solution requires a base class that exposes the Id property. I assumed that the questionner must have this too since Car and User both implement Model and they refer to obj.Id in the Update method. I have found a single base class for my Models very useful for other purposes too but I am sure it is not for everyone so thanks for highlighting the point.

Answer (score 0):

I use next workaround: detach entity and load again

```
public T Reload<T>(T entity) where T : class, IEntityId
{
    ((IObjectContextAdapter)_dbContext).ObjectContext.Detach(entity);
    return _dbContext.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == entity.Id);
}
```