# context.Entities.Create() with default constructor

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

When using Entity Framework DbContext, to create a new entity and wrap it in a proxy class, one does :

```
var product = context.Products.Create();
```

that creates a proxy for the entity, but doesn't allow for contructor variable initialization like :

```
var product = new Product { name = "Product Name" };
```

---

Question 1 :
Is there any way to create a proxy for an already instanciated object ? like :

```
context.Products.CreateProxyFrom(product)
```

---

Question 2 :
Is there any way to create the a class initialization like

```
context.Products.Create() { name = "Product Name" };
```

---

I know both option does not exist, I'm wondering is there some shortcut or workaround around this.

---

Question 3:

Having `PaymentCheck : Payment` (inheritance)
I can only do `context.Payments.Create();`
but I need a `PaymentCheck` instance. how can I do a create of `PaymentCheck` ?

Comment: 1. Nope. 2. Nope. 3. Use `context.Payments.Create<PaymentCheck>()`

Comment: You might find this interesting. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16811976/150342

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the big deal with just setting property values after the proxy has been created, but if you absolutely *must* have the property value setting on the same line and aren't afraid to pollute your IntelliSense a bit, you can always get a bit functional with extension methods:

```
public static T Apply<T>(this T input, Action<T> action)
{
    action(input);

    return input;
}
```

Usage:

```
Product product = context.Products.Create()
    .Apply(p => p.name = "Product Name")
    .Apply(p => p.category = 42);
```

Comment: It's not because of one liner. it's because of updating massive old code using default constructor.

Comment: Then you're pretty much stuck with refactoring - unless you're ready to roll your own `CreateProxyFrom` extension method which will take in a concrete object instance, create a proxy and copy the property values using Reflection or AutoMapper-type tool while taking care not to touch navigational properties. It's dangerous and wasteful, but doable if you really can't afford to go down the refactoring route.

Comment: went down the refactor route... added a new Question to the matter.