# Change textbox value if change combobox value (System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.')

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I will try autoload textbox value if I change my combobox index
but dont understand if I load my form I receive this error?

### [image]

I handle my null and if I ignore this line everything is fine !

this is my form

---

[image]

this is my repositories

AreaRepository

```
public string GetAreaNamebyAreaID(int areaID)
{
    var result = db.btbArea.SingleOrDefault(g => g.AreaID == areaID);

    if (result == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return result.AreaName;
}
```

HowzehRepository

```
public string GetHowzehNamebyHoezehID(int howzehID)
{
    var result = db.btbHowzeh.SingleOrDefault(g => g.HowzehID == howzehID);
    if (result == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return result.HowzehName;
}
```

PaygahRepository

```
public string GetPaygahNamebyPaygahID(int paygahID)
{
    var result = db.btbPaygah.SingleOrDefault(g => g.PaygahID == paygahID);
    if (result == null)
        return string.Empty;

    return result.PaygahName;
}
```

I will try load my textbox value if I change my combobox index

```
private void frmAreasManage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load AreaComboBox Source from AreaTable
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
    { 
        cmbAreaNumber.DataSource = db.AreaRepository.Get();
        cmbAreaNumber.DisplayMember = "AreaNumber";
        cmbAreaNumber.ValueMember = "AreaID";
    }
}

private void cmbAreaNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = cmbAreaNumber.SelectedValue.ToString();
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
        {
            {
                //Load HowzehhComboBox From HowzehTable Filter By AreaID
                cmbHowzehNumber.DataSource = db.HowzehRepository.GetNameIDByFilter(selectedValue);

                cmbHowzehNumber.DisplayMember = "HowzehNumber";
                cmbHowzehNumber.ValueMember = "HowzehID";

                //Get AreaName from AreaTable Filter By AreaID
                txtAreaName.Text = db.AreaRepository.GetAreaNamebyAreaID(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
            }
        }
}

private void cmbHowzehNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedValue = cmbHowzehNumber.SelectedValue.ToString();
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))
        {
            //Load PaygahComboBox From PaygahTable Filter By HowzehID
            cmbPaygahNumber.DataSource = db.PaygahRepository.GetNameIDByFilter(selectedValue);

            cmbPaygahNumber.DisplayMember = "PaygahNumber";
            cmbPaygahNumber.ValueMember = "PaygahID";
            //Get HowzehName from HowzehTable Filter By HowzehID
            txtHowzehName.Text = db.HowzehRepository.GetHowzehNamebyHoezehID(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
        }
}

private void cmbPaygahNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        //Get HowzehName from HowzehTable Filter By HowzehID
        txtPaygahName.Text = db.PaygahRepository.GetPaygahNamebyPaygahID(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
    }
}
```

Comment: In the screenshot the `selectedValue` is not a number. use `if(int.TryParse(selectedValue, out int res)){...}` instead of `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(selectedValue))`. Also make sure `cmbAreaNumber.Items` are valid numbers.

Comment: The debugger information shows that `cmbAreaNumber.SelectedValue` is not a number, but is instead a `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies`. This is likely to relate to the following issue: [Why is EF returning a proxy class instead of the actual entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9501471/why-is-ef-returning-a-proxy-class-instead-of-the-actual-entity)

Comment: @HamidRezaMohammadi if i ignore this line //txtAreaName.Text = db.AreaRepository.GetAreaNamebyAreaID(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
other line work correct 
translate to farsi
hamidreza jan man in line ro ke commend mikonam hamechi khoobe yani hata vaghti form load mishe error nadaram ( yani age iradi daram tooye load form man etefagh miogte - hes mikonam tooye load form bayad ye kari konam ke combobox man kolan null bashe ke changeindex ejra nashe ta vaghti ke yeky entekhabesh kone ) ama nemidoonam chetori man taze shoro kardam

Comment: I'm so sorry for my first comment, I have a mistake and didn't pay attention to the actual data type. As Ross suggestion it's not a number, but is instead a `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies`.

Comment: @RossGurbutt i turn off Lazy Loading Enabled and use set Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; but my problem not solved

Comment: Try to replace problem line `txtAreaName.Text = db.AreaRepository.GetAreaNamebyAreaID(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));` with the next one: `txtAreaName.Text = db.AreaRepository.GetAreaNamebyAreaID(((Area)cmbAreaNumber.SelectedValue).AreaID);`.

Comment: I supposed that *Area* is the type of the objects returned by the method *db.AreaRepository.Get()*. This method is used to set *DataSource* of the *cmbAreaNumber*. Instead of the *Area* you should write actual name of the of the objects returned by the method *db.AreaRepository.Get()*.

Comment: From screenshot I found out that required type is *btbArea*. Try to replace the word *Area* with *btbArea*.

Comment: @IliarTurdushev i use this code txtAreaName.Text = db.AreaRepository.GetAreaNamebyAreaID(((btbArea)cmbAreaNumber.SelectedValue).AreaID); my problem solved if i open form ( first load ) but if i change combobox value i receive this error ( System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Gim.DataLayer.btbArea'.' )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

To fix your problem make the next changes in the method `frmAreasManage_Load`:

```
private void frmAreasManage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Load AreaComboBox Source from AreaTable
    using (UnitOfWork db = new UnitOfWork())
    { 
        // At first assign properties DisplayMember and ValueMember.
        cmbAreaNumber.DisplayMember = "AreaNumber";
        cmbAreaNumber.ValueMember = "AreaID";

        // And then assign DataSource property of the cmbAreaNumber.
        cmbAreaNumber.DataSource = db.AreaRepository.Get();
    }
}
```

---

### Explanation

*Why do we need to assign `ValueMember` before `DataSource` property?*

When we assign `DataSource` property the first item of the assigned collection becomes `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox`. This triggers `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event.

If we assign `DataSource` before `ValueMember` (and therefore `ValueMember = null`) then `CombobBox.SelectedValue` is the first item of the collection itself. In your case `SelectedValue` is an object of type `btbArea`. Therefore when I asked you to use the next code in the `cmbAreaNumber_SelectedIndexChanged` handler

```
txtAreaName.Text = db.AreaRepository.GetAreaNamebyAreaID(((btbArea) cmbAreaNumber.SelectedValue).AreaID);
```

it fixed the problem for first load. But then you got `System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'Gim.DataLayer.btbArea'`. This error occured because then `ValueMember` property was assigned to the value `AreaID` and from that moment `ComboBox.SelectedValue` was the value of the property `int AreaID` of the `btbArea`.

If we assign `ValueMember = "AreaID"` and then `DataSource` then whenever `ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event is raised, `SelectedValue` is the value of the property `AreaID`. And therefore to prevent `SelectedValue` of being an object of type `btbArea` (situation when `ValueMember = null`) we must at first assign `ValueMember` and then `DataSource`.

Comment: this is really class room, thanks for your information